# Does C# lock object require lazy initialization

Tags: c#, multithreading, lazy-initialization

I may be missing some blindingly obvious documentation somewhere, but is static readonly member variable guaranteed to be initialized properly for use as a lock object?

In short, I have a library class that performs operation on an external resource that should only have a single instance touching it at any one time (don't have to worry about another process, it's only on a single process). The library class itself can have multiple instances in multiple threads, so in order to ensure that only one instance access said resource at a time, I need to use a lock.

I've seen a lot of lock object declaration like this.

`private static readonly object _lockObj = new object();`

Can this guarantee that multiple threads won't, by bad timing, initialize the two objects at the same time and lock on two objects? Or should I be creating the lock object like this.

`private static readonly Lazy<object> _lockObj = new Lazy<object>(() => new object());`

P.S. I'm referring to the C#'s `lock(_lockObj){...}` keyword for locking.

Comment: Locking can be done on any object. If what your saying would be true a `static readonly` field could have multiple values which would be not intended. As long as they are accessing the same class you should be good to go. Be wary of generic classes tho ;)

Comment: The CLR guarantees that types will be initialized once per appdomain. Static field initializers are run inside the type initializer before the body of the type's static constructor (if it has one). So assuming two threads are activating a method in the same appdomain, there is no possibility that there will be a race where they get different lock objects.

Comment: If it didn't work like this, then I don't see how your solution would help. You'd just move the problem with the risk you have two `Lazy` instances that then initialise two different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime guarantees only one copy of a static member field. You can even use it without any instances of the class. It would be safe for use as a lock object.

Comment: So even if the object is a bit more complex, like semaphore, I can do this. `public static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3)` without using Lazy<> initialization?

Comment: Yes, _semaphore is constructed before it can be used.

Comment: I don't think you need to use Lazy all the time. It's not like your application is a resource critical one.

Comment: @SterlingW The complexity of the type doesn't matter. The static initializer is guaranteed to run in a serial fashion - internally it uses a global lock.